# objective-c. TableView cells have the same address

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

every 12 cells in my tableview have the same address, this results in a problem: when i address to one cell, all cells with that address get called

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"datacell";
DataCell *cell = (DataCell*) [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
if (cell==nil) {
    cell= [[DataCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
}
// Configure the cell...

if (indexPath.row==1) {
    cell.backgroundColor= [UIColor redColor];
}
return cell;
```

for example here, although i set red color to only one cell, every 13-th cell gets red background. So i have 4 cells with red background. I have no idea what is going on :@:@

Comment: Why do you have no idea? This is one of the most common questions answered here. Just search and you will find.

Comment: i did search, could u help me with a link?

Comment: Example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20781556/strange-behaviour-on-table-view-with-core-data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Table view cells are *reused* when you scroll. For that reason, you have to
*always* set the properties of the cell, e.g.:

```
if (indexPath.row==1) {
    cell.backgroundColor= [UIColor redColor];
} else {
    cell.backgroundColor= [UIColor clearColor];
}
```